# Spring test with @DataJpaTest can't autowire class with @Repository (but with interface repository works!)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, spring-test

I'm trying to understand why I can't autowire a class repository but I can autowire a interface repository in the **same package** for the **same test**. The same repository works as expected when I start the application.

First, the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.person.repository.PersonRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultPersonbleBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultPersonbleBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultPersonbleBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultPersonbleBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultPersonbleBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultPersonbleBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 28 more
```

I have a very simple example. The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository; // fail...

    @Autowired
    private PersonCrudRepository personCrudRepository; // works!

    @Test
    public void findOne() {
    }
}
```

The repository class:

```
@Repository
public class PersonRepository {
    //code
}
```

The repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

After a [bad experience with this same error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48186530/2387977), I'm trying to find some detail in my configuration or test what is responsible for this problem. Another possibility is the `@DataJpaTest` does not have support for class repositories.

Comment: BTW is not necessary declare Repository annotation in your interface. Behind the scenes the proxy created by Spring Data add that one and even Transactional

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think I was right about the problem. After find a [post on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8501) and read the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test):

> @DataJpaTest can be used if you want to test JPA applications. By
> default it will configure an in-memory embedded database, scan for
> @Entity classes and configure Spring Data JPA repositories. Regular
> @Component beans will not be loaded into the ApplicationContext.

My `PersonRepository` is considered a regular `@Component`, because it is not a Spring Data JPA repository (the interface is). So, it is not loaded.

The alternative solution is to use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@DataJpaTest`.

The disadvantage with this solution is that will load **all** your context while running your test and, with this, disabling the test slicing. But do the job.

Another option, still using `@DataJpaTest`, is include a `@Repository` filter annotation, like this:

```
@DataJpaTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = Repository.class))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I still have same exceptions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313098/spring-boot-datajpatest-fail-with-java-lang-illegalstateexceptioncaused-by-giv

Comment: BTW - about "The disadvantage with this solution is that will load all your context ", you can use `SpringBootTest` with `WebEnvironment.MOCK` to test with only the server side (Nothing about the Web). It reduces of course in some way the impact of performance.

Answer (score 24):

Just another alternative might be `@Import` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084739/384674.

Comment: Yes, I think this is THE solution

Comment: This fixed for me the same problem