# Spring Boot 5 multiple JUnit JPA test files wiring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have two tests files in project.
One is testing directly my persistence layer :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindByEmail_thenReturnUser() {
        // given
        User user = new User("email@email.com", "12345678", "Some Name");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        User found = repository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

        // then
        assertThat(found.getName()).isEqualTo(user.getName());
        assertThat(found.getEmail()).isEqualTo(user.getEmail());
        assertThat(found.getPasswordHash()).isEqualTo(user.getPasswordHash());
    }
}
```

The other one is testing a service using the persistence layer :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @Test
    public void testSuccessfullUserCreation() {
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWrongEmailUserCreation() {
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything", "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.INVALID_EMAIL);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTooShortPasswordUserCreation() {
        String shortPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.minPasswordLength - 1, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", shortPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.WRONG_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTooLongPasswordUserCreation() {
        String longPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.maxPasswordLength + 1, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", longPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.WRONG_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxLengthPasswordUserCreation() {
        String maxPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.maxPasswordLength, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", maxPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMinLengthPasswordUserCreation() {
        String minPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.minPasswordLength, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", minPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReservedEmailUserCreation() {
        String email = "email@email.com";
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser(email, "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
        res = service.createUser(email, "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.RESERVED_EMAIL);
    }
}
```

First, my service autowiring wasn't working (`UnsatisfiedDependencyException`) so I had to add :
`@ComponentScan("my.service.package")` annotation to the test class.

This made the tests of `UserServiceTests` work when they were run independently (using eclipse to run only this class).

But when running all the tests of my app (in eclipse or with a good old `mvn clean test`), I had the same error on the same test class.

I tried adding the same component scan annotation to the other test class (`UserTests`) then everything worked.

I removed the component scan annotation from `UserServiceTests` and it still works.

I obviously deduced that the order the tests are executed matters.

Here are my 3 questions, the real one being the last one :

1. In the first place why do I have to put this component scan annotation even if my class is properly annotated `@Service` (so should be detected as a bean) ?
2. How is it that the order of tests matters ?
3. How can I have multiple JPA tests files that would run with a proper dependency injection independently ?

Here is my service class :

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public static final int minPasswordLength = 8;
    public static final int maxPasswordLength = 50;

    public static enum UserCreationResult {
        OK, INVALID_EMAIL, RESERVED_EMAIL, WRONG_PASSWORD_LENGTH, UNKNOWN_ERROR
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserCreationResult createUser(String email, String password, String name) {
        if (password.length() < minPasswordLength || password.length() > maxPasswordLength) {
            return UserCreationResult.WRONG_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
        }
        if (!EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email)) {
            return UserCreationResult.INVALID_EMAIL;
        }
        final User existingUser = repository.findByEmail(email);
        if (existingUser != null) {
            return UserCreationResult.RESERVED_EMAIL;
        }
        final User user = repository.save(new User(email, password, name));
        return user == null ? UserCreationResult.UNKNOWN_ERROR : UserCreationResult.OK;
    }
}
```

And there is my `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.somedomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>My App</name>
    <description>My app's description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347088/spring-test-with-datajpatest-cant-autowire-class-with-repository-but-with-in) I was able to make my tests work with proper configuration.

In my `UserServiceTests`, the service was basically not autowired because that's the expected behavior of `@DataJpaTest` : it doesn't scan for regular beans.

So I used `@SpringBootTest` for this class and removed the component scanning in both test classes.

After that, some of my service tests were failing because with `@SpringBootTest`, the database is not reset after each test.

I added a simple repository cleaning after each service test and everything works fine.

This question still remains :

> How is it that the order of tests matters ?

Here are my new test classes :

Service tests :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @After
    public void cleanUsers() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccessfullUserCreation() {
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWrongEmailUserCreation() {
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything", "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.INVALID_EMAIL);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTooShortPasswordUserCreation() {
        String shortPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.minPasswordLength - 1, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", shortPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.WRONG_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTooLongPasswordUserCreation() {
        String longPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.maxPasswordLength + 1, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", longPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.WRONG_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxLengthPasswordUserCreation() {
        String maxPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.maxPasswordLength, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", maxPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMinLengthPasswordUserCreation() {
        String minPassword =
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(UserService.minPasswordLength, "0"));
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser("anything@anything.com", minPassword, "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReservedEmailUserCreation() {
        String email = "email@email.com";
        UserCreationResult res = service.createUser(email, "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.OK);
        res = service.createUser(email, "1234567890", "Test");
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo(UserCreationResult.RESERVED_EMAIL);
    }
}
```

JPA tests :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindByEmail_thenReturnUser() {
        // given
        User user = new User("user@user.com", "12345678", "Some Name");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        User found = repository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

        // then
        assertThat(found.getName()).isEqualTo(user.getName());
        assertThat(found.getEmail()).isEqualTo(user.getEmail());
        assertThat(found.getPasswordHash()).isEqualTo(user.getPasswordHash());
    }
}
```