# Unit testing of Hibernate Queries in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, unit-testing

How do I write unit-test (slice test) cases for Hibernate Criteria queries written in the app? The `@DataJpaTest` isn't working in this case and seems to be working just for Spring Data JPA. Below is the unit test code

```java
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class AppDaoTests {

    @Autowired
    private AppDao appDao;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void getAppWithName() {
        App expected = AppStub.getApp();
        App app = appDao.getApp("dummy");

        assertThat(app.getName()).isEqualTo(expected.getName());
    }
}
```

Below is the error log that is received.

```java
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

2022-09-05 14:53:42.344
             INFO  [<clinit>] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version : HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.3.Final
2022-09-05 14:53:42.441
             INFO  [logStarting] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger : Starting AppDaoTests using Java 11.0.15.1 on QCLAP1884P890 with PID 24153 (started by vaibhav.swarnkar in /Users/vaibhav.swarnakar/IdeaProjects/shift(payout)/landing)
2022-09-05 14:53:42.448
             INFO  [logStartupProfileInfo] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
2022-09-05 14:53:43.600
             INFO  [multipleStoresDetected] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-09-05 14:53:43.602
             INFO  [registerRepositoriesIn] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-05 14:53:43.702
             INFO  [registerRepositoriesIn] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 91 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-09-05 14:53:44.579
             INFO  [getConnection]       com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-09-05 14:53:45.146
             INFO  [getConnection]       com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-09-05 14:53:45.365
             INFO  [logPersistenceUnitInformation] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-09-05 14:53:45.431
             INFO  [logVersion]                    org.hibernate.Version : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-09-05 14:53:45.700
             INFO  [<clinit>] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-09-05 14:53:45.857
             INFO  [<init>]            org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2022-09-05 14:53:47.171
             INFO  [initiateService] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-09-05 14:53:47.184
             INFO  [buildNativeEntityManagerFactory] org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-09-05 14:53:48.067
             INFO  [logStarted] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger : Started AppDaoTests in 6.479 seconds (JVM running for 8.856)



============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration matched:
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.PooledDataSourceAvailable PooledDataSource found supported DataSource; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceInitializationConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlR2dbcScriptDatabaseInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.JdbcTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager', 'org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor' (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'jdbcTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.sql.init.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - NoneNestedConditions 0 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration.SqlInitializationModeCondition.ModeIsNever @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.sql.init.mode=never) did not find property 'mode' (SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration.SqlInitializationModeCondition)

   TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration#testEntityManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#platformTransactionManagerCustomizers matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)



Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration



2022-09-05 14:53:48.090
            ERROR  [prepareTestInstance] org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1f14f20c] to prepare test instance [test.dao.sql.dao.AppDaoTests@79aba813]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'test.dao.sql.dao.AppDaoTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'test.dao.sql.AppDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119) ~[spring-test-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

Comment: Maybe using @Import will help as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081589/datajpatest-needing-a-class-outside-the-test/41084739#41084739

Comment: It did help in the JPA Test, however below error comes when using @DataMongoTest 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Better to raise a new question for that and tag it appropriately